# Tomee+Microprofile UnsatisfiedResolutionException

Tags: ejb, cdi, apache-tomee, openejb, microprofile

everybody!
Could you give me advice about such an issue.
I have a simple test project in order to test using Microprofile config. 
Field of my test class I test:

```
   @Inject
   @ConfigProperty(name = "injected.value")
   private String injectedValue;
```

So this is the dependencies section of my pom:

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.microprofile/microprofile -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile</groupId>
            <artifactId>microprofile</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I build the war and then:
1. when i deploy war into the tomee 8.0.1-microprofile (tomee-maven-plugin with tomeeClassifier set up to **microprofile**) -> then all works OK.
2. BUT when i deploy war into the tomee 8.0.1-plus (tomee-maven-plugin with tomeeClassifier set up to **plus**) -> then i got exception:

```
org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansDeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [java.lang.String] is not found with the qualifiers 
Qualifiers: [@org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty(name=injected.value, defaultValue=org.eclipse.microprofile.config.configproperty.unconfigureddvalue)]
for injection into Field Injection Point, field name :  injectedValue, Bean Owner : ...
```

More over in case 1 (deploy to tomee 8.0.1-microprofile) when i change pom dependencies to:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile.config</groupId>
            <artifactId>microprofile-config-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

i got the error:

```
 org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansDeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [java.lang.String] is not found with the qualifiers 
Qualifiers: [@org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty(name=injected.value, defaultValue=org.eclipse.microprofile.config.configproperty.unconfigureddvalue)]...
```

Please could anybody help me with this issue? 
I need to use Microptofile in the prod and for now, I can't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the plus and plume version to work, you must include the following property in **system.properties**:

tomee.mp.scan = all

reference:
http://tomee-openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/MicroProfile-Integration-in-Plus-and-Plume-td4686818i60.html

another way is using the tomee plugin and adding this property in pom.xml :

```
<systemVariables>
       <tomee.mp.scan>all</tomee.mp.scan>
 </systemVariables>
```

Comment: Daniel Dias Thanks a lot!. System.properties file works for me.

Comment: great Vitali :)